# get raw (non-decoded) querystring key/values

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

How do I get the raw (non-decoded) values that are in the querystring?

I found **Request.Url.Query**, which does successfully give me the raw querystring itself. However, it gives me a type 'string' and the entire QS contents: how do I get the key/value pairs?

I did find [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), however that forces me to do decoding. I need the raw name/value pairs.

Must I implement my own querystring parsing for this? Has anyone done one I can use that ignores encoding? I found the [Mono implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpUtility.cs) however this also forces encoding.

Thanks!

Edit: the reason why I'm looking for this is because someone (not me!) wrote some code to encrypt a value and place it in the querystring. However they forgot to encode it first. The decoding that Request.Querystring() is doing is making it impossible to decrypt around 50% of these because the encryption leaves things like '+' and '.'

Comment: Why are the encoded key/value pairs more valuable than the unencoded ones?

Comment: It's simple enough to re-encode the value returned from `Request.QueryString[key]`.

Comment: the reason why I'm looking for this is because someone (not me!) wrote some code to encrypt a value and place it in the querystring. However they forgot to encode it first. The decoding that Request.Querystring() is doing is making it impossible to decrypt around 50% of these because the encryption leaves things like '+' and '.'

Comment: @dferraro: And you aren't able to change the code that puts that value in the query string, right?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, correct. People have already received emails to these hyperlinks and we cannot go back in time and change them now or re-send the emails

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree. Unfortunately this is not my decision :(

Comment: You have a bug in the code that needs to be fixed. Your current solution may produce broken URLs as software layer between a user clicking on the link and the request being sent to the server will interpret the link according to standards. Which you did not abide. (By "you", I don't mean you personally.) You probably won't be able to make it work in 100% of cases. Better to fix the url generation and send apologies to your customers.

Comment: @zespri , we did fix the URL generation code to now use encoding. My concern is 'legacy' hyperlinks that people have saved and are keeping around. In which  cases would this not work 100%?  My first instinct was to communicate to the customer that links needed to be re-generated. However it was shot down. I would like to understand better so I can make a case for it.

Comment: It's possible that browsers e-mail clients etc may change the url. The plus sign in the query string portion is equivalent to %20. So it's a possibility that you click on a link with a plus in it and get %20 on the server - both means the same thing for the browser and for a web server too. But not for you, and you don't have a good way of saying what that was originally. There could be similar cases I have not thought of.

Comment: @zespri thanks. I didn't know that browsers could do encoding automatically. I just tried testing this using Outlook, clicked the link and it opened in FireFox. The server got the raw string fine. I just tested it in Gmail using IE, Chrome & FireFox and none of them did any kind of decoding. They all got the raw string and my 'hacky' code worked. In which cases do you think it will fail? Thanks again!

Comment: If you test all most likely clients/browsers on your target client OS I think you are more or less safe in practical terms. The problem is that you can't test them all. I know for sure that some browsers change the *visual representation* of url when you paste it, this is most prominent for non latin char sets. However I have not observed the server side to see how these changes are reflected. As long as you are comfortable that you tested them all for all possible characters/browsers/clients you should be ok.

Answer (score 9):

<strike>`Request.QueryString` should give you a `NameValueCollection` with all the key/value pairs, already decoded.</strike>

Sorry, I misunderstood the question. You'll need to parse it yourself, but it shouldn't be that difficult:

```
Request.Url.Query.Split('&').Select(pair => pair.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

This is, of course, assuming that the unencoded values in your URLs don't contain "&" or "=" values. If they do... well, that's kind of what URL encoding is there for, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, but I need the unencoded values. The raw values that you see in the browser address bar

Comment: @dferraro: Sorry, the question was unclear. To me, "unencoded" means "decoded." The values in the address bar are "URL-encoded" values.

Comment: +1. Obviously if someone failed to encode it may contain `&` and `=` in wrong places too...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, I was already updating with a note to that effect. This is why encode values. :-)

Comment: I suppose I will have to hard-code the parsing to work only with the keys I am expecting. Because you are correct, the encryption could leave an '=' sign or '&'.

Comment: @dferraro in any case you will have to roll your own parser as your requirements are quite.... unique.